# English word or phrase that is a more general version of "forge" or "foundry"

Tags: synonyms, american-english, noun-phrases

I have been google searching and racking my brain trying to think of a word or phrase that captures the essence of "a place the specializes in making things". I like both the term forge and foundry, but they are specific to blacksmithing and metalworking. My particular instance is for a place where people go to get software made, so it probably doesn't matter but any suggestions or unusual words for a "maker space" would be great.

The first part of my desired title is a common noun that is often found in groups, so or example: "ant forge" makes me think we are crushing up ants and shaping them into new things (roughly desireable), but ant factory seems like we are mass-producing ants.

Ideally the noun would correspond to a place or operation that exists or existed in the past, and isn't taken by some other tech buzzword. The heuristic I am going by is in paragraph 2. Basically does ant + word suggest that you are making ants or Making something with/out of ants? The latter case is the one I am looking for. My top choice right now is "Ant Foundries"

Comment: How about "a factory". Or maybe "a workshop"?

Comment: @Cascabel I don't dislike that suggestion, but I am looking for something a bit unusual, and because my name involves a common noun both those terms go from my desired effect of suggesting that we are making something out of that noun, to suggesting that we are mass producing that noun. I will edit the post to clarify.

Comment: Which "hits" from a thesaurus did you consider, and why did you reject them?

Comment: So..."software factory." Perhaps you may recall that Andy Warhol used that name for a similar project. ...and I think "forge" has been over-used in Compu terms. This is not really a good place to ask for names.

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't outright reject them just yet, but I consider "Yard", "Workshop", "Mint", "Mill", "Works and "Shop" to all be close to what I'm looking for. They all seem to imply the wrong thing to me from the aforementioned test (eg "Ant Mint", "Ant Shop" make it sound like I am making ants).

Comment: If it is specialized software, maybe "software boutique". Unless that sounds too "trendy". I would write an answer but I feel that this will close soon for any number of reasons, but mostly Opinion-based.

Comment: Maybe 'incubator'? (edit:but it's trendy too... I personally liked 'software factory')

Comment: @Cascabel yes that is too trendy for me, what makes you say the question has closed? Have I violated some rule?

Comment: No,  I just said that it _may_ close. For some users this may not be useful, however much fun it might be.

Comment: @SConroy incubators are already a known thing in tech, where aspiring entrepreneurs go to have their needs taken care of while they work on a product.

Comment: OK. We are now at the point where you have to go through the comments (especially yours) and figure out how you should revise your question. Tell us why some suggestions do not work, but in the _question._

Comment: @Cascabel I tried to edit to include new clarity around my heuristic. Much of that clarity has come from the questions so I am happy to add it.

Comment: Yes, I know... I just thought it might fit here too, but you're right it's not a good suggestion esp. if you are looking for something original. Are you open to allusions? e.g. software tank (rather then think-tank). Otherwise drawing a blank here.

Comment: @SConroy sure I am open to allusions, software tank makes me think of the war vehicle and not the think-tank though :)

Comment: Guys, sooner or later we are gonna get hit by a Mod asking everyone to go to Chat.

Comment: @Cascabel I didn't even know there was a chat. I haven't been using stackexchange much in the past 3 years

Comment: I googled that and found that you have to use the JS console or wait for an admin to boot ya [per this SE conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a naming request where the selection criteria seems to be arbitrary; this is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild leap and suggest:

**Ant Labs**

It doesn't have a necessarily "mass production" feel to it, but it does have an experimental "think tank" feel to it—in addition to indicating a place where things are actually made (and remade).

Comment: Nice, but we are not really about coining neologisms. Naming, especially computer stuff, is off-topic here.

Comment: @Cascabel I don't interpret this as an example of a neologism; I interpret it as  a request for a synonym of *forge* or *foundry*, not for the name of something. (The question isn't specifically about naming something.) The use of *Ant* is only in my answer because it was mentioned in the question itself—and it serves the same purpose as other *drop-in* words that more typical synonym requests would provide. But the main point is that *lab* is a possible synonym based on the criteria stated in the question and all of the comments that helped to clarify it. Even if Marvel does come to mind. ;)

Comment: BTW... I gave you an uptick here, ... thought it was an original idea. And all too often, we are depending on links and odd quotes.

Comment: @Cascabel Cheers. Honestly, I felt strange *not* providing a link to a dictionary definition of the word. But it didn't seem like there could be any confusion in this case.